# Firm Sizes over the business cycle

Tags: macroeconomics, industrial-organisation, academic-graduate, business-cycles, reference-request

There has been a lot of evidence about the firm size distribution (as measured in employment) being Pareto (see for example [Luttmer 2007](http://qje.oxfordjournals.org/content/122/3/1103.full.pdf)), but what are the properties of this distribution over the business cycle?

Comment: So, Luttmer describes some static distribution of firm size and you want to know if there is any data on how this distribution changes over time?

Comment: @jmbejara Exactly.

Answer (score 3):

These guys [(paper)](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219525904000160) claim the distribution is still power-law, but steeper in recessions and flatter in booms.

[Content added after suggestion]

> While it is well known that the distribution of firm sizes (in the US
>   at least) looks like a power law distribution, these guys look at
>   whether it changes in shape over the business cycle.
>
> They show that (in log-log space) the distribution is actually a power
>   law in both recessions and expansions, but its not the same power law,
>   its steeper in recessions and flatter in booms, meaning that large
>   firms become relatively larger in booms than in recessions, or
>   alternatively that there is  a lot of entry of small firms in booms.

Comment: This is a link only answer. Please copy the gist of the relevant information from the paper you linked.